# How to get gradl sync going again on Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

After having this issue on Mac OSX, I reinstalled everything for Android Studio. (Studio itself, SDK's), ... Gradle Sync just does not work anymore. Anybody experiences this also? JAVA SDK Installed is 1.8.0_161.

"Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 70" on gradl sync (see screenshot)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj8bO.png)

[android studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k33D3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Bintray was experiencing an outage this morning. This is where a lot of Gradle's Android dependencies are hosted, so it was most likely affecting your Gradle Sync Process. Keep an eye on the status page here, and try again if it turns green. http://status.bintray.com/

Comment: The outages I also saw this morning. The downloads were not coming through - lots of 502. But it is getting worse with the bytecode thing. Is this also depending on this outage?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of JDK old versions. Go to the project structure and change your project to latest JDK version like 1.80_72 or later

Comment: I explicitely told gradle to use the java version I updated in the gradle.properties file in my project with this line: org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home (so no, this is not the issue i guess). Somehow I have a feeling this has something to do with Kotlin, don't ask me why...

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my Android Studio (on Ubuntu 14.04) to version 3.1.4 I also experienced a build problem:
Gradle sync failed: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 70
Exception details: error in bytecode
Found out it was due to an old JDK version I have installed locally. 
Instead of updating my local JDK I changed the project settings to use the embedded JDK, which, by the way, Android Studio says is the recommended option, and that solved the problem.